# Extract SSH server key from server itself

Tags: ssh

In order to connect to an SSH server, it must be listed in `known_hosts`.

Is there some command that I can run *on the server* which will generate the text that needs to be put into this file?

(Surely the server knows what its own key is. Getting that information directly out of the server itself seems like it ought to be the most secure method. So I'm a little surprised that there doesn't seem to be a way to do that...)

Comment: SSHFP DNS records are the best for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man ssh-keyscan`

It scans local or remote IP addresses to return the public key.

For example, `ssh-keyscan 127.0.0.1`